# How to test the method that reads the data from the excel file in java?

Tags: java, junit4, properties-file, testcase

[image]
The above picture shows the excel file containing the Facebook data.

The class `FacebookDataExtraction` reads the data from the Excel file and stores the data as list of row objects as shown in the code.
I have made use of the config.properties file to get the file path. The contents of config.properties file are: `FILE_NAME=D:/Refreshed_data_daily/all_hue_posts_in_excel.xlsx.`

```
public class FacebookDataExtraction {

//private static final String FILE_NAME="D:/Refreshed_data_daily/all_hue_posts_in_excel.xlsx";
private static final String SHEET_NAME="nextv54plus_actions";
XSSFWorkbook workbook;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        FacebookDataExtraction obj= new FacebookDataExtraction();
        List<FacebookFields> displayList= new ArrayList<FacebookFields>();
        displayList=obj.readFromExcel();
        System.out.println("The Size of the list is:"+ displayList.size());
    }

    public List<FacebookFields> readFromExcel() {
        List<FacebookFields> fbList= new ArrayList<FacebookFields>();
        try
        {
            ReadPropertyFile data= new ReadPropertyFile("config.properties");
            FileInputStream fin= new FileInputStream(data.getPropertyFor("FILE_NAME"));
            workbook= new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
            int sheetIndex=0;
            for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
                readSheet(sheet,sheetIndex ++, fbList);}

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fbList;
    }

    private void readSheet(Sheet sheet, int sheetIndex , List<FacebookFields> fbList) {

        if(SHEET_NAME.equals(sheet.getSheetName())){
            workbook.removeSheetAt(sheetIndex);
            return;
        }
        for (Row row : sheet){
            if (row.getRowNum() > 0)
                fbList.add(readRow(row));}

    }

    private FacebookFields readRow(Row row) {

        FacebookFields record= new FacebookFields();
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            switch (cell.getColumnIndex()) {
            case 0: record.setName(cell.getStringCellValue()); 
            break; 
            case 1: record.setId(cell.getStringCellValue()); 
            break; 
            case 2: record.setDate(cell.getStringCellValue());
            break; 
            case 3: record.setMessage(cell.getStringCellValue());
            break; 
            case 4: record.setType(cell.getStringCellValue());
            break; 
            case 5: record.setPage(cell.getStringCellValue());
            break; 
            case 6: record.setLikeCount(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
            break; 
            case 7: record.setCommentCount(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue())); 
            break; 
            case 8: record.setShareCount(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue())); 
            break; 
            }
        }

        return record;
    }

    public boolean containsData() {  

        List<FacebookFields> checkList= readFromExcel();    
        return !checkList.isEmpty() ;
    }

    }
```

The `FacebookFields` class(not shown here) contains the set methods for the data extracted!
How to I write a test case for method `readRow()` or how to test whether each field of the column contains data?

Comment: unit test? integration test? what value do you want your test to bring?

Comment: You made the method `private`, which means that it is an internal method. You should try to focus on testing the `public` methods of the class. If you design a/multiple good test of your public methods, you will automatically test if the private method did its work.

Comment: @dom  its unit testing I want.

Comment: @Timo Yeah private method cannot be tested. Had it been public how do i test it? Its just that I want to check if the data in each column is not null. How do I do that?

Comment: Split this class up into many smaller classes that do only one thing (Single Responsibility Principle), and then build up your main method with all the small classes by injecting your dependencies via the constructor (Dependency Inversion Principle). Each small class should be testable without knowledge other classes and will build up.

Comment: Its difficult to make from your comment!

Comment: If you create a test for `readFromExcel()` and check the contents of the list you should be there. If necessary you can add a breakpoint to the internal method and debug why it gave you null.

Comment: @Timo I have created a test which checks that list contains the data.

 public void testWhetherListConatinsData(){
  FacebookDataExtraction fbDataList= new FacebookDataExtraction();
  assertEquals(fbDataList.containsData(), true); 
 }

Comment: I created an answer to have some clear formatting and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

- So, you want to test readRow() method which would return FacebookFields.
- Since it is private, you could not directly do unit testing on this private method, but your main objective seems to be testing this method. Let's think about refactoring/redesigning a bit here.
- You could create a class `FacebookFieldRetriever`, which has a public method `retrieveFromRow()`, which returns `FacebookFields`.
- So, each time `FacebookDataExtraction` encounters a row from excel sheet, it creates an object of `FacebookFieldRetriever` and invokes `retrieveFromRow()` to get `FacebookFields` object modelled from that row.
- As we have passed the class design stage, let's move on to unit testing. So, now you have a public method: `retrieveFromRow()` which you could actually unit test, assuming that you have a row object which contains cells containing the actual values from the excel sheet. (Basically, we are focusing on testing switch-case logic).
- FacebookFieldRetriever Class

  `class FacebookFieldRetriever{

    public FacebookFields retrieveFromRow(Row row) {

    FacebookFields record= new FacebookFields();
    for (Cell cell : row) {
    switch (cell.getColumnIndex()) {
    case 0: record.setName(cell.getStringCellValue()); 
    break; 
    case 1: record.setId(cell.getStringCellValue()); 
    break; 
    case 2: record.setDate(cell.getStringCellValue());
    break; 
    case 3: record.setMessage(cell.getStringCellValue());
    break; 
    case 4: record.setType(cell.getStringCellValue());
    break; 
    case 5: record.setPage(cell.getStringCellValue());
    break; 
    case 6: record.setLikeCount(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
    break; 
    case 7: record.setCommentCount(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue())); 
    break; 
    case 8: record.setShareCount(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue())); 
    break; 
    }
    }

    return record;
    }

    }`
- Example of Unit test Below:

class FacebookFieldRetrieverTest
    {

```
private final String TEST_NAME = "Mark Zuckerberg";
private final String TEST_id = "4";
private final String TEST_DATE = "2015-10-13;                                
private final String TEST_MSG = "Welcome to Facebook";                                 
private final String TEST_TYPE = "SomeType";                                
private final String TEST_PAGE = "SomePage";
private final String TEST_LIKECOUNT = 6;
private final String TEST_COMMENTCOUNT = 7;
private final String TEST_SHARECOUNT = 8 ;


public void testFacebookFieldRetriever()
{
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheettemp = wb.createSheet();
Row row = sheettemp.createRow(1);

Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(TEST_NAME);

Cell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue(TEST_id);

Cell cell2 = row.createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue(TEST_DATE);

Cell cell3 = row.createCell(3);
cell.setCellValue(TEST_MSG);

Cell cell4 = row.createCell(4);
cell.setCellValue(TEST_TYPE);

Cell cell5 = row.createCell(5);
cell.setCellValue(TEST_PAGE);

Cell cell6 = row.createCell(6);
cell.setCellValue(TEST_LIKECOUNT);

Cell cell7 = row.createCell(7);
cell.setCellValue(TEST_COMMENTCOUNT);

Cell cell8 = row.createCell(8);
cell.setCellValue(TEST_SHARECOUNT);

FacebookFieldRetriever fbRetriever = new FacebookFieldRetriever();
FacebookFields fbFields = fbRetriever.retrieveFromRow(row);

assertEquals(fbFields.getName(), TEST_NAME);
assertEquals(fbFields.getId(), TEST_id);
assertEquals(fbFields.getMessage(), TEST_MSG);
assertEquals(fbFields.getLikeCount(), TEST_LIKECOUNT);
assertEquals(fbFields.getShareCount(), TEST_SHARECOUNT);
assertEquals(fbFields.getCommentCount(), TEST_COMMENTCOUNT);
assertEquals(fbFields.getPage(), TEST_PAGE);
assertEquals(fbFields.getType(), TEST_TYPE);
}
}
```

`

- You could test in the way given above. Hope it helps.

Comment: The thing is I don't know what data will be present in the excel sheet!! Because the excel data will be refreshed everyday via a software. 
Though in my test case I have a test which checks if the list contains data like Tom has posted! But I wanted something like to test the column data iterated over the row to check if data is present in it

Comment: You seem to imply that you dont want to do a unit testing, but some kind of testing to check if readRow() is actually returning FacebookFields corresponding to a particular row. Then, I guess, you should have another class which parses excel file, gets FacebookFields for each row. Use this class to test your readRow(), by doing some equals() on both the object.

Comment: Yeah I want to do unit testing in which I need to check if the value read in the column iterated over the row is not null. 
Creating another class which includes parsing the excel file will have the same logic to extract the data as it was in the class FacebookDataExtraction.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an excel that contains "expected value" for the first row in your sample excel, the following test could be a start. Note that the `equals` for Lists might be a bit crude, especially since I'm not sure how it treats the internal order of the elements by heart.

*Edit* I've added a constructor parameter to the `FacebookDataExtraction` class that takes the filename to the excel file it should extract data from.

```
@Test
public void testWhetherListConatinsData(){ 
    List<FacebookFields> expectedList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Fill the expected list here:
    expectedList.add("expected value");
    // ... Add more if you want to...

    // Read in data.
    FacebookDataExtraction fbDataList= new FacebookDataExtraction("path/to/testdata/test_with_strange_first_name.xlsx");

    List<FacebookFields> listOfFields = fbDataList.readFromExcel();
    // Good check to start with.
    assertEquals(listOfFields.containsData(), true); 

    // Actual data check.
    assertEquals("Lists not the same", expectedList, listOfFields);
}
```

Comment: The excel data is something that I don't know in prior because the excel data is getting refreshed daily! I just know the fields contained in the excel i.e columns(1st row) namely name,id,type etc etc

Comment: But you should be able to create small excel sheet that looks just like the one you will see in production? This is your test data file that is fully under your control and contain anything you would like to see tested.
You cannot make a unit test that depends on data that changes all the time, if you want to make it a stable test. (What if the data gets refreshed and your test crashes and you notice only after a new data set is forced on your tests? Not reproducable)

Comment: Is it correct way to test the method  **readSheet** by mocking the Sheet class (making the method public) and ? Testing the "if" condition and the for loop in two separate test cases? I don't know whether it is the correct way how to do it!

Comment: You could, but I think it would be easier to get your test setup straight. I've added some things to my example.